# How to display records as fields in a query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

How would I produce a result like this :

| Date | Australia | United States | Germany |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24th | 13000 | 14003 | 25608 |
| 24th | 24800 | 20080 | 30502 |

From this table:

| Country | Date | TotalVaccinations |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AUS | 24th | 13000 |
| USA | 24th | 14003 |
| DEU | 24th | 25608 |
| AUS | 25th | 24800 |
| USA | 25th | 20080 |
| DEU | 25th | 30502 |

I tried this :

```
Select Date, A.TotalFullyVaccinated AS 'Australia', B.TotalFullyVaccinated AS 'United States'
From TotalVaccinations A, TotalVaccinations B
Where A.Date = B.Date
And A.Country= 'AUS'
Or B.Country= 'USA'
;
```

But results look like this (Australia field is empty) :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can build the `SUM` of the TotalVaccinations and then `GROUP` the result `BY` day.

Use `CASE WHEN` to split the values into the different columns with the matching name.

Thus, values having the country name 'AUS' will be summated in the column 'Australia', those having the country name 'USA' in the column 'United States' and those having the country name 'DEU' in the column 'Germany'.

This query will produce the expected outcome:

```
SELECT 
yourdate AS date,
SUM(CASE country 
WHEN 'AUS' THEN TotalVaccinations END) AS 'Australia',
SUM(CASE country 
WHEN 'USA' THEN TotalVaccinations END) AS 'United States',
SUM(CASE country 
WHEN 'DEU' THEN TotalVaccinations END) AS 'Germany'
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY yourdate
ORDER BY yourdate;
```

See here a working example according to your sample data:
[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sA_QurJP)